# Wait for element to load then edit with jquery

Tags: jquery, load

I can't tell you the exact accordion I am working with but essentially here is my problem.

I need to wait for an element (in this case an accordion) to load it's data and then I want to manipulate it. I believe this is an ajax call and if I could edit the ajax callback then there would be no issue. However I have no access or control of what happens there sadly. Is there a good way of doing this? I mean, setting a timeout is just sloppy and probably wouldn't work for slower connections etc.... not a route I would want to go down. Maybe I'm missing something? Are there any jquery methods for this? I couldn't see any in the docs. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there not a callback function on your accordion for when it has loaded?

Comment: That's just it Pete I can't get to the ajax request itself (no permission to do this sadly.) Cheers for the reply though!

Answer (score 0):

You may try standard `$( document ).ready()` function, but as far as I know it can be applied only to the whole document. https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jakub! It's already in the doc.ready. I think window.onload would be more suitable but was wondering if there was a method that would just wait until the element I am targetting has finished loading only.

Answer (score 0):

Why not build a interval poll that loops, checking on a timed bases for a property from the successful payload?

For the issue you've described, this seems like the most logical approach given you seem to be under the impression that a `setTimeout` is a sloppy method to use.

```
       // A basic setTimeout loop, mimicking setInterval
       var doStuff = function () {
        // Do stuff
        setTimeout(doStuff, 1000);
       };
      setTimeout(doStuff, 1000);
```

Or as Pete said, hook into the callback function within your AJAX call.

Comment: Cheers David!
Yeah that's probably the best shout. I'll give that a shot. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem T, give it a go and let me know how you get on and best of luck!

Comment: Hey David, it worked so many thanks for that. After a bit of pushing, it looks like I am going to gain access to the AJAX call so I will be able to update the callback manually.Cheers for taking the time to help me with this one.

Comment: Thats great to hear man, it'll defiantly be a a lot cleaner with you being able to edit the AJAX call.